# Amazon S3 REST API 403 error c#

Tags: c#, rest, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get some code working to fetch a file from S3 using the REST API via C#. I've seen other people doing similar things but for some reason I keep getting a 403 error. I've tried to do the same thing with the AWS SDK for .Net and it works so I assume it's the way I'm creating the authorization header.

Is anyone able to shed any light on this please?

```
string awsAccessId = "***";
string awsSecretKey = "***";
string bucketName = "thebucket";

string httpDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +0000\n");
                string canonicalString = "GET\n"
                                        + "\n"
                                        + "\n"
                                        + "x-amz-date:" + httpDate + "\n"
                                        + "/" + bucketName + "/readme.txt";

                // now encode the canonical string
                Encoding ae = new UTF8Encoding();
                // create a hashing object
                HMACSHA1 signature = new HMACSHA1();
                // secretId is the hash key
                signature.Key = ae.GetBytes(awsSecretKey);
                byte[] bytes = ae.GetBytes(canonicalString);
                byte[] moreBytes = signature.ComputeHash(bytes);
                // convert the hash byte array into a base64 encoding
                string encodedCanonical = Convert.ToBase64String(moreBytes);

                // Send the request
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://" + bucketName +".s3.amazonaws.com/readme.txt");
                request.Headers.Add("x-amz-date", httpDate);
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "AWS " + awsAccessId + ":" + encodedCanonical);
                request.Method = "GET";

                // Get the response
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                Console.Read();
```

Comment: Why not use the sdk if it works?

Comment: I'm hoping to put it into an SSIS script task

Answer (score 3):

I tested your code, it works! you just need an extra \n plus change http to https and you're done.

```
 string stringToConvert = "GET\n"
                          + "\n"
                          + "\n"
                          + "\n"
                          + "x-amz-date:" + timeStamp + "\n"  
                          + "/" + bucketName + "/" + FileName;
```

Amazon Rest API don't have a good documentation, the lack of examples makes everyone go to the SDK instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the *only* problem, but it looks like a definite problem:

```
+ "x-amz-date:" + httpDate + "\n"
```

`x-amz-date` is the header that supercedes the Date: header in the HTTP request itself, but in the string to sign, you just put the date, without "x-amz-date:" or anything in front of it, according to the examples:

```
GET\n
\n
\n
Tue, 27 Mar 2007 19:36:42 +0000\n
/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationRequestCanonicalization

There is only one correct signature that can be generated for a request.  S3 is going to generate that signature, and compare it to the one you sent, so there's not a single byte of room for error in the string-to-sign.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I made the modification but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is the 403 message returning an error that gives you the string to sign and tells you the signature does not match, or no? What does the error say? (in the response body)

Comment: The error message is stating that the signature does not match: <Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>