# Amazon s3 C# auth

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, rest, web-services

I need help with aws s3 Rest auth.

I have the next code:

```
        string url = "http://fxstestcandles.cloudapp.net/pairs/history/eurusd";
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        WebHeaderCollection headers = (request as HttpWebRequest).Headers;
        string httpDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ") + "+0000";

        string canonicalString = "GET\n\n\n " + httpDate + "\n/";
        Encoding ae = new UTF8Encoding();
        HMACSHA1 signature = new HMACSHA1();
        signature.Key = ae.GetBytes("551a656b548e8466f555d540156b5a");
        byte[] bytes  = ae.GetBytes(canonicalString);
        byte[] moreBytes = signature.ComputeHash(bytes);
        string encodedCanonical = Convert.ToBase64String(moreBytes);
        headers.Add("Authorization", "AWS " + "25496a25b6554f54b5e6" + ":" + encodedCanonical);
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        Stream stream =  response.GetResponseStream() as Stream;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
        int nRead =0;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        do
        {
            nRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, nRead);
        } while (nRead > 0);


        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string responseString = encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        System.Console.Write(responseString);
```

I need help i'm geeting the next error: (403) Forbiden.

The authentication is done following the steps on this link: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html. 
The credentials are: 
PublicKey: 25496a25b6554f54b5e6 
PrivateKey: 551a656b548e8466f555d540156b5a 
You just need to use the date for the SHA1, there is no need to use the entire the request string. 
Example headers: 
Date: Mon, 26 Mar 2007 19:37:58 +0000 
Authorization: FXST AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:frJIUN8DYpKDtOLCwo//yllqDzg=

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be your canonicalString and your HttpWebRequest , I had the same problem, please see the solution in this post: [Amazon S3 REST API 403 error c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689484/amazon-s3-rest-api-403-error-c-sharp/26167524#26167524)

That's sad how Amazon API is badly documented