# Read XML file located in AWS throws "the remote name could not be resolved https://compcdn.cloud.com"

Tags: c#, xml, amazon-s3

I have an XML file located on our company Cloud Site (this is an amazon s3 server) (https://compcdn.cloud.com/books.xml) and I am trying to read the XML from that location using
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("https://compcdn.cloud.com/books.xml");
But unfortunately it throws the following exception "The remote name could not be resolved compcdn.cloud.com"
I am not sure what I am missing here.
I am not sure If I have to pass any credentials over here to access the URL, if so can you please let me know how can I do that..
Thank you and appreciate your feedback.
Inner Exception
System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'compcdn.cloud.com'\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)\r\n   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)\r\n   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()\r\n   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)\r\n   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)\r\n   at comp.internalServices.DownloadService.GetDownloadableDriversFromConfig() in c:\WorkSpace\git\master\comp.internalServices\DownloadService.cs:line 139

Comment: Do I have to pass any credentials to read from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- EDIT --

Yes you need to authenticate your call. Read this post for a c# example of how to add your authentication for your headers:

[Amazon S3 REST API 403 error c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689484/amazon-s3-rest-api-403-error-c-sharp/26167524#26167524)

Read this to better understand the process in general:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

Comment: No it is all listed as books.xml only

Comment: Is the url you provided a sample url? Or the exact url you're trying to load? I ask because that url doesn't exist in my webbrowser

Comment: ,We cannot access the URL directly, we need to authenticate to access the URL

Comment: Then yes you need to authenticate in the code too. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I added the authentication and it still shows the same error for me..can you please help

Comment: @Michael Thank you for the condescending comment.

Comment: Yeah, that was a little out of line on my part.  I get annoyed with questions where the answer should have been intuitively obvious or easily google-able, and answers that offer suggestions that might be useful in other contexts, but which have overlooked the core problem at hand... but I certainly could have been more courteous about it. Apologies for my lapse in basic civility. (Seriously.)

Answer (score 0):

> The remote name could not be resolved compcdn.cloud.com

This error message is self-explanatory, and nothing to do with authentication.

The remote name could not be resolved *from DNS*.

Either you are using the wrong hostname, or you or a vendor has a DNS misconfiguration, or you're using the wrong hostname, because `compcdn.cloud.com` is not valid.

```
$ nslookup compcdn.cloud.com

** server can't find compcdn.cloud.com: NXDOMAIN
```

Pulling up the site in Chrome shows a similar error:

> This webpage is not available
>
> `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

`NXDOMAIN` means no such hostname exists.

> (this is an amazon s3 server)

That seems unlikely.